# Does idris support a way to collapse symmetrical statements into one?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, idris

I'm new to functional programming, so working through 'Type Driven Development with Idris'.
Give a function maxMaybe that can compute the max between two Maybe Doubles, defines as below

```
maxMaybe : Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maxMaybe Nothing y = y
maxMaybe x Nothing = x
maxMaybe Nothing Nothing = Nothing
maxMaybe (Just x) (Just y) = Just (max x y)
```

Is there a way to collapse the following cases into just one, since the positions don't matter?

```
maxMaybe Nothing y = y
maxMaybe x Nothing = x
```

I would also be curious to know if this kind of thing is handled generally in other purely functional programming languages like Haskell or OCaml

```
maxMaybe : Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maxMaybe Nothing y = y
-- maxMaybe x Nothing = x
maxMaybe Nothing Nothing = Nothing
maxMaybe (Just x) (Just y) = Just (max x y)
```

> maxMaybe (Just 5) (Nothing)
> maxMaybe (Just 5) Nothing : Maybe Integer

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
maxMaybe : Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maxMaybe mx my = [| max mx my |] <|> mx <|> my
```

but it will probably be more expensive at runtime as you'll redo
a lot of the case analysis unless enough compiler optimisations
kick in to give you something essentially equivalent to your
original solution.

Comment: This answer works, thans @gallais. Could you explain your answer a little bit? Looking at the solution, Im not quite sure whats going on in terms of operators + idris language features.

Comment: @JordanSimba `[| max mx my |]` is [idiom brackets](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#idiom-brackets) which means "apply `max` to the contents of `mx` and `my`". I think`<|>` is an operator used in `Alternative` which means "if that failed (here with `Nothing`), try this alternative (here the contents of `mx` or `my`)"

Answer (score 1):

You have asked both answers in Haskell and in OCaml, and so far only answer in Haskell have been provided. Therefore, I will give the OCaml equivalent, and not repeat the Haskell code.

Since the question is specifically about merging together symmetrical branches of a match statement, here is how your version could have been written in OCaml:

```ml
let max_option x y = match x, y with
  | None, y -> y
  | x, None -> x
  | None, None -> None
  | Some x, Some y -> Some (max x y)
```

And here is how the folded version would be

```ml
let max_option x y = match x, y with
  | None, v | v, None -> v (* two branches are merged *)
  | Some x, Some y -> Some (max x y)
  (* the `None, None` branch has been deleted as it was redundant *)
```

But, for this specific case, since `'a option` (`Maybe a` in Haskell) is a monad, it would be more idiomatic to use monadic let bindings:

```ml
let max_option x y =
  let (let>) = Option.bind in
  let> x = x in
  let> y = y in
  Some (max x y)
```

Since the example is a bit contrived, you get some weird `let> x = x` statements.
You could probably use more higher-kind functions, but I don't think it would result in much more idiomatic OCaml code, contrary to Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell an idea might be to work with the `Min` semigroup and wrap use this:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Semigroup (Max (Max, getMax))

maxMaybe :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maxMaybe = on ((fmap getMax .) . (<>)) (fmap Max)
```

you can easily generalize this to any `Semigroup` like structure:

```
semiFunc :: (Functor f, Semigroup (f b)) => (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> f a -> f a -> f c
semiFunc f g = on ((fmap g .) . (<>)) (fmap f)
```

then `maxMaybe` is a special case of `semiFunc` with `maxMaybe = semiFunc Max getMax`.